# How to interrupt loop/process using terminal input in C++ on a Linux application

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am writing a Linux command line application that ultimately leads to data acquisition from a piece of hardware. The nature of the data acquisition is that it will feed data to the program consistently at some defined data rate. Once the user enters into RxData (the receive loop), we do not want to stop unless we get a command from the terminal to tell it to stop. The problem I foresee is that using getchar() will hang the loop every iteration of the while loop because the program will expect the user to enter input. Am I wrong in this behavior?

On a side note, I know that when working with embedded devices, you can simply check a register to see if the buffer has increased and use that to determine whether or not to read from the buffer or not. I do not have that luxury on a Linux application (or do I?). Does some such function (let's call it getCharAvailable) which I can run, check if data has been input, and THEN signal my program to stop acquiring data?

I can't simply use SIGINT because I need to signal to the hardware to stop data acquisition as well as add a header to the recorded data. There needs to be a signal to stop acquisition.

Comment: I suggest implementing a callback function handler for signals, that (when a sigint signal is received) performs all the needed cleanup, stopping of the hardware, then exits the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux (or any other Unix flavour), you can use `select` to look if there is available data on 2 (or more) file descriptors, sockets or any other thing that can be *read*. (It is the reason why this system call exists ...)

Comment: This was the most straight forward solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use the `ncurse` library and use `getch` in `non-delay` mode

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this library existed. This looks like it should work. I will give it a shot and report back.